# How to add csv file in a 2d array vb.net?

Tags: vb.net, csv

```
User, 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9

Joe, 34,3,32,1,3

John, 32,2

Tom, 98,34,23

Dave, 56, 53, 32,1,22,6,5
```

I have this csv file that I would like to put in a 2d array.

```
Private Sub GetElement()
    'Read the data from the cv file
    Try
        Dim fileIn As String = "mel.csv"
        Dim fileRows(), fileFields() As String
        Dim count As Integer = 0
        textBox.Text = String.Empty
        If File.Exists(fileIn) Then
            Dim fileStream As StreamReader = File.OpenText(fileIn)
            fileRows = fileStream.ReadToEnd().Split(Environment.NewLine)
            For i As Integer = 0 To fileRows.Length - 1
                fileFields = fileRows(i).Split(",")
                If fileFields.Length >= 2 Then
                    For x As Integer = 0 To fileFields.Length - 1
                        If x = 0 Then
                            For e As Integer = 0 To fileFields.Length
                                ele.Add(fileFields(e))
                                listBox.Items.Add(ele(e))
                            Next
                        End If
                    Next
                    count = count + 1
                End If
            Next
        Else
            textBox.Text = fileIn & " not found."
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        textBox1.Text = ex.Message
    End Try
End Sub
```

I was able to receive the first line only and then I have added it to a list box. In the MainWindow class I have declared two list of string to store the column and rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this....

```
Imports System.Data.OleDb

Public Class Form1

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim folder = "Path to your CSV folder (do not include the file name here)"
    Dim CnStr = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" & folder & ";Extended Properties=""text;HDR=No;FMT=Delimited"";"
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    ' change Test.csv to your csv file name here
    Using Adp As New OleDbDataAdapter("select * from [Test.csv]", CnStr)
        Try
            Adp.Fill(dt)
        Catch ex As Exception
        End Try
    End Using

    DataGridView1.DataSource = dt
End Sub

End Class
```

this will import the CSV file then display it straight into a DataGridView control (list box has problem with columns)... hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you work with objects since you are working with an OO'programing language . It would be simple and more optimised if you created a new class . And then create a new object after reading each line . `Dim u as new User(x,y,z...)` And to organise your data, use a hashtable or a linkedlist (don't know if it's called like this for vb.net).  Then you can fill in your listbox from objects that are in your hashtable or linkedlist.